# What is the "accessTokExtra" parameter in everyauth's facebook connect user creation callback function?

Tags: node.js, connect, everyauth

The code for everyauth's facebook findOrCreateUser() function is as follows:

```
everyauth.facebook.findOrCreateUser(function(session, accessToken, accessTokExtra, fbUserData){ });
```

Can anybody share what the `accessTokExtra` parameter is exactly?

Best,

Sami

Answer (score 0):

It contains access token's expiration date.